# Firebase push works on componentDidMount and not on a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Almost everything is on the title, please see the code below

```
saveData() {
   let favdata = this.state.UserInput;
    firebase.database().ref(`/favorites/`)
    .push({ favdata })
    .then(() => {
      alert('Data saved!')
     });
  };
```

The function cannot read the state and by the way I am getting this error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.UserInput')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind your function to `this` correctly for example like this:

```
saveData = () => {
  // function here
}
```

Here is more material on the same topic: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: No worries! Please read the whole of React's "Quick Start" since it usually has 90% of the answers you need in at start of your React career :)